# ¿Como borro una llave foranea de una tabla en SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla en donde quiero un query donde pueda eliminar la llave foranea

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes conocer el nombre de la llave foránea que quieres eliminar, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo vamos a eliminar la llave foránea llamada: ***FK__test__idempresa__3C69FB99***  de la tabla ***test***

Ejecutamos:

```
alter table test
drop constraint FK__test__idempresa__3C69FB99;
```

Luego de ejecutar el script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]